# How to highlight a user selected text which is not contained within a single text node using vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the user selection then replace them with a mark tag on each text node inside  of an element if the user selected two text node which are child, grandchild (for ex: inside a tag which is a child), so surround the first node with `<mark>first text node</mark>` and the second one like this `<mark><a>partial of second</a></mark><a>rest which is not highlighted</a>`

```html
<div>
<p id="first" data-selectable-paragraph="">
At the very first age, JavaScript was called LiveScript. An engineer named Brendan Eich has created JavaScript in 1995. There was a little confused about the name with Java and JavaScript. After several months Microsoft released JScript with Internet Explorer 3. After that Netscape submitted JavaScript to Ecma International. In 1999 ECMAScript edition 3 launched and it has stayed pretty much stable ever since.
</p>
<p>
Another Selection <span> you could do</span>
</p>
<p id="second" data-selectable-paragraph="">
Range is something I discovered recently, which again showed me that the possibilities with the Javascript and the DOM are truly endless. As stated on Mozilla’s developer site, range ‘represents a fragment of a document that can contain nodes and parts of text nodes’. So, if you create of select a section of a document, range could tell you the nodes that it contains, its starting and ending positions relative to the document, it can clone its content ,and much more. (Read more from the docs: 
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range">
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range
</a>)
</p>
</div>
```

let's say that the user selected 3 texts and highlighted them which I want to result in this structure-> Brief explanation: if the parent or grandparent has data-selectable-paragraph then highlight the text nodes inside the element and its parent if it is the grandchild

```html
<div>
<p id="first" data-selectable-paragraph>
At the very first age, JavaScript was called LiveScript. An engineer named Brendan Eich has created JavaScript in 1995. There was a little confusion about the name with Java and JavaScript. After several months Microsoft released JScript with Internet Explorer 3. After that Netscape submitted JavaScript to Ecma International. In 1999 ECMAScript edition 3 <mark>launched and it has stayed pretty much stable ever since.</mark>
</p>
<p class='second' data-selectable-paragraph>
<mark>Another Selection </mark><mark><span> you could do</span></mark>
</p>
<p id="third" data-selectable-paragraph>
<mark>
Range is something I discovered recently, which again showed me that the possibilities with the Javascript and the DOM are truly endless. As stated on Mozilla’s developer site, range ‘represents a fragment of a document that can contain nodes and parts of text nodes’. So, if you create of select a section of a document, range could tell you the nodes that it contains, its starting and ending positions relative to the document, it can clone its content ,and much more. (Read more from the docs:
</mark>
<mark>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range">
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range
</a>
</mark>
<mark>)</mark>
</p>
</div>
```

what i've found so far was `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.hasAttribute("data-selectable-paragraph");`
on mouse up but i don't know what to do next

EDIT:

**Selected text**

1. launched and it has stayed pretty much stable ever since. `its parent is the first P.`
2. Another Selection you could do `its parent is the second P.`
3. Range is something I discovered recently, which again showed me that the possibilities with the Javascript and the DOM are truly endless. As stated on Mozilla’s developer site, range ‘represents a fragment of a document that can contain nodes and parts of text nodes’. So, if you create or select a section of a document, the range could tell you the nodes that it contains, its starting and ending positions relative to the document, it can clone its content, and much more. (Read more from the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range)
   `its parent is the third P.`

There is before after snippets so please take them into consideration

Comment: I got excited when I saw `surroundContents` for `Range` objects, but it doesn't quite work for this scenario :( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/surroundContents

Comment: yea it doesn't work, unless it is text node.

Comment: please add more detail with example what user selected, what was current parent and grandparent of selection, what changes happen to selected text, parent, grandparent,. etc.

Comment: @Chandan i've edited it, but if u looked at the before, after snippet you'd have seen it.

Comment: @Boudyhesham i was not able to understand if user select all text one at a time or whole at once

Comment: You've got just one line of code. `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.hasAttribute("data-selectable-paragraph");` And you aren't showing it in context. Do you have a complete page we could look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a start. I'm simply allowing you to mark the text once, not set and unset the marks.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("get_selection")[0];
    btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var wrap = ["A"]; // nodes that should be wrapped in mark (rather than node's textContent wrapped in mark)
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

        if (!range.startContainer.isSameNode(range.endContainer)) {
            // get all nodes within the range commonAncestorContainer node
            var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
                range.commonAncestorContainer,
                NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL
            );

            var nodeList = [];
            var currentNode = treeWalker.currentNode;
            while (currentNode) {
                nodeList.push(currentNode);
                currentNode = treeWalker.nextNode();
            }

            var start = null; // index that our selected nodes start
            var end = null; // index that our selected nodes end
            var selNodes = nodeList.filter(function (val, i) {
                // filter the node list
                var node = nodeList[i];
                start = start ?? (val.isSameNode(range.startContainer) ? i : null); // if same as start node
                end = end ?? (val.isSameNode(range.endContainer) ? i : null); // if same as end node
                var lesser = start == null || i <= start; // is before start node?
                var greater = end != null && i >= end; // is after end node?
                return (
                    !lesser &&
                    !greater &&
                    !node.isSameNode(range.endContainer.parentNode) && // node is not same as end node's parent
                    node != undefined &&
                    node != null &&
                    node.textContent.replace(/\t|\n/g, "") != "" &&
                    node.textContent.replace(/\t|\n/g, "") != undefined &&
                    !node.contains(range.endContainer) && // node does not contain end node
                    !node.isSameNode(range.endContainer.parentNode) // node is not same as end node's parent
                );
            });

            // mark node at start of selection
            var sParent = range.startContainer.parentNode;
            var sText = range.startContainer.textContent;
            var mark = document.createElement("mark");
            // wrap a tags in mark
            if (
                wrap.includes(sParent.nodeName) &&
                sText.replace(/\t+|\n+/gm, "") ==
                    sText.substring(range.startOffset).replace(/\t+|\n+/gm, "")
            ) {
                var node = sParent.cloneNode(true);
                mark.append(node);
                sParent.after(mark);
                sParent.remove();
            } else {
                mark.textContent = sText.substring(range.startOffset);
                range.startContainer.textContent = sText.substring(range.startOffset, -1);
                range.startContainer.after(mark);
            }

            // mark node at end of selection
            var eParent = range.endContainer.parentNode;
            // console.log("end parent: ", eParent);
            var eText = range.endContainer.textContent;
            var mark = document.createElement("mark");
            // wrap a tags in mark
            if (
                wrap.includes(eParent.nodeName) &&
                eText.replace(/\t+|\n+/gm, "") ==
                    eText.substring(range.endOffset, -1).replace(/\t+|\n+/gm, "")
            ) {
                var node = eParent.cloneNode(true);
                mark.append(node);
                eParent.after(mark);
                eParent.remove();
            } else {
                mark.textContent = eText.substring(range.endOffset, -1);
                range.endContainer.textContent = eText.substring(range.endOffset);
                range.endContainer.before(mark);
            }

            // mark nodes in between start and end
            selNodes.forEach(function (val, idx) {
                var currentNode = selNodes[idx];
                var mark = document.createElement("mark");
                if (currentNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                    // if text node, insert mark after node and remove node
                    mark.textContent = currentNode.textContent;
                    currentNode.after(mark);
                    currentNode.remove();
                } else {
                    if (wrap.includes(currentNode.nodeName)) {
                        var node = currentNode.cloneNode(true);
                        mark.append(node);
                        currentNode.after(mark);
                        currentNode.remove();
                    } else {
                        // reset the node's html and append mark
                        mark.textContent = currentNode.textContent;
                        currentNode.innerHTML = "";
                        currentNode.appendChild(mark);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            var parentNode = range.startContainer.parentNode;
            var mark = document.createElement("mark");
            if (wrap.includes(parentNode.nodeName)) {
                var node = parentNode.cloneNode(true);
                node.textContent = sel.toString();
                mark.append(node);
                parentNode.after(mark);
                parentNode.remove();
            } else {
                var sText = document.createTextNode(
                    range.startContainer.textContent
                        .substring(range.startOffset, -1)
                        .toString()
                );
                var eText = document.createTextNode(
                    range.endContainer.textContent.substring(range.endOffset).toString()
                );
                mark.textContent = sel.toString();
                range.startContainer.after(eText);
                range.startContainer.after(mark);
                range.startContainer.after(sText);
                range.startContainer.remove();
            }
        }
    });
};
```

```html
<button class="get_selection">Set Markers</button>
<div>
  <p id="first" data-selectable-paragraph>
    At the very first age, JavaScript was called LiveScript. An engineer named Brendan Eich has created JavaScript in 1995. There was a little confusion about the name with Java and JavaScript. After several months Microsoft released JScript with Internet
    Explorer 3. After that Netscape submitted JavaScript to Ecma International. In 1999 ECMAScript edition 3 launched and it has stayed pretty much stable ever since.
  </p>
  <p class='second' data-selectable-paragraph>
    Another Selection <span> you could do</span>
  </p>
  <p id="third" data-selectable-paragraph>

    Range is something I discovered recently, which again showed me that the possibilities with the Javascript and the DOM are truly endless. As stated on Mozilla’s developer site, range ‘represents a fragment of a document that can contain nodes and parts
    of text nodes’. So, if you create of select a section of a document, range could tell you the nodes that it contains, its starting and ending positions relative to the document, it can clone its content ,and much more. (Read more from the docs:

    <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range">
            https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range
        </a> )
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for it is not the 100% that i want but it is 75% what i want really thanks bounty ended but i'm gonna renew it again, can you briefly explain how treewalker is walking through it cause i've never dealt with treeWalker API, if you select a text node and text node of anchor tag you're marking the text that is inside the anchor  tag, but what i'm looking for is cloning the tag itself and only putting selected text node inside the anchor inside mark tag it is not Required it is optional but if you help me with that i appreciate it.

Comment: @Boudyhesham well, if the anchor tag is only partially selected, you wouldn't want to mark the entire thing, would you?

Comment: yea i wouldn't want to mark the entire tag, but clone the tag itself (without any childNodes) and remove selected text node and put it in the cloned tag and put it in the dom, Note: that if the partially selected text is in the beginning of achor tag i will insert the cloned one before original anchor tag, if it is on the end i'll insert it after original Anchor tag

Comment: and another non related comment how did you know about treewalker i mean i have 1 year experience and never had the chance to know it, can you tell me if there are good books to become a better js dev, thanks and i really appreciate it.

Comment: @Boudyhesham Honestly just exploring the internet helped me find it. Like looking around codepen and stackoverflow helps you find new things. I use MDN for documentation btw, I like it better than ww3 schools, it just seems more "put together" to me.

Comment: can you briefly explain how treewalker is working here.

Comment: @Boudyhesham The treewalker api allows you to get nodes within a specified node (range.commonAncestorContainer which is the common ancestor of the selections start node and end node), you can use the NodeFilter to filter the types of nodes to show. I am using show_all to get ***all*** node types. Then loop through the nodes using a while loop. While `treewalker.currentNode` exists, push it to the nodelist array and set the current node as `treewalker.nextNode` if the next node does exist, break out. Here is the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker

Comment: @Boudyhesham Forgot to mention that my answer and codepen have been updated to wrap `a` tags in the `mark` tag, only when the entire tag is selected, I don't understand exactly what you want when the `a` tag's text is partially selected.

Comment: Note that you're removing the rest of the a tag btw

Comment: Oh, it is amazing! Really what I need! Is it hard to make it remember the highlights when reload the page and remove marked ones when long press? @Souleste

Comment: @RGS You could most likely store the ranges via cookies. To remove on long press you could look at the childNodes of the parent and previousSibling, nextSibling of the mark node.